# What is Negative_size exception in Bjarne's book?

Tags: c++, exception, throw

2nd edition of *A Tour of C++* of Bjarne's Stroustrup goes into templates in chapter 6.

This is the code on page 80 that I am uncertain about. There is a `Negative_size` exception but I haven't been able to find it with a google search and adding `std::` to it gave me the error:

```
error: ‘Negative_size’ is not a member of ‘std’
   26 |         throw std::Negative_size{};
```

```cpp
template <typename T>
class Vector
{
public:
    explicit Vector(int s);
    ~Vector()
    {
        delete[] elem;
    }

    T &operator[](int i);
    const T &operator[](int i) const; // for const Vectors
    int size() const
    {
        return sz;
    }

private:
    T *elem;
    int sz;
};

template <typename T>
Vector<T>::Vector(int s)
{

    if (s < 0)
    {
        throw std::Negative_size{}; // where the compilation error occurs
    }
}
```

I also didn't see it mentioned in the [errata](https://www.stroustrup.com/tour2_errata.html).

**EDIT:**

Responses to comments

- Chapter 6 is about templates.
- I have read the book from the first chapter and so I haven't skipped anything. I wouldn't have posted a question otherwise.
- I initially posted code to figure out what the error is but I am including the rest to reproduce the problem. I didn't want to include extra code that wasn't asking about the issue itself but this was requested.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we could see that error. The shown code raises other errors, starting from the undefined identifier `Vector`.

Comment: There is no standard `Negative_size` type. From context, I assume it is a hypothetical type used for illustrative purposes. For the purpose of illustrating this example, it doesn't matter how `Negative_size` is implemented.

Comment: `Negative_size` is not a standard type (and neither is `Vector`) in C++.   Either `Negative_size` is described somehow (e.g. as pseudo-code) in some section of the book that you have skipped or it is a hypothetical type that may be inferred from context to be "an unspecified type thrown if a negative size is detected".

Comment: Are you one of who is `using namespace std;`? Then I doubt it's a book fault.

Comment: *"adding `std::` to it gave me the error"* -- Not too surprising. A capitalized identifier is unlikely to be in the `std` namespace. Most identifiers in the standard library are all lowercase, while a few are all caps (and the all caps examples I can think of are not in a namespace -- they tend to be preprocessor macros).

Comment: `struct Negative_size{};`  It's not in `std::`.

Comment: @Peter, it isn't skipped. I have read the book from the first page. I also get that `Vector` isn't a part of it because it is defined there in the code and it is the example code for templates.

Comment: @273K, I have included the rest of my code.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, could you make that your answer?